# Can mirthconnect 3.0.1.7051 choke on a large file without having heap error?

Tags: mirth

Can mirthconnect 3.0.1.7051 choke on a large file without having heap error?
We are using Mirthconnect 3.0.1.7051 on a linux machine (Redhat, I think). The Linux machine has 16 gb, and java heap (in mirth) is set to 12gb. We have a javascript reader channel attempting to read a delimited text file, and convert it to xml (after checking some things). Other settings are Durable message delivery, remove content and attachments on completion, Polling type =(interval),Polling frequency = 2 minutes,
Source queue off – respond after processing, Destination/channel type = channel writer, Queue retry = always, retry interval every 10,000 ms.
The delimnited text file is close to 80KB. At first, when we had much less memory in machine and set in heap, it would fail to read the file and show heap error in mirth log. now, with more memory, it is not throwing heap error but mirth stops reading the input file somewhere in the middle of it, and then starts reading it again. The result is that two incomplete xml files are produced, with some overlapping data, and no apparent errors in the log.

Comment: this is a Linux box, so is clearing the Java cache relevant?

Comment: I am currently processing 600MB+ delimited files, so I do not think that is the issue.  If you were not using a Javascript connector I would have imagined you had custom unbatching code running. An error in that code could cause weird things to happen including partial messages and continuous pickup of files.